# /etc/network/interfaces doesn't always take affect

Tags: 12.04, networking, server, dns

For some reason my eth0 does not have internet on reboot sometimes.  I am using a static ip.  I can ping my gateway, but I am unable to ping dns servers, or anything out of my network.  It seems that when my internet does work(Usually but just restarting enough times), my /etc/resolv.conf has a nameserver in it.  It is empty when I have no internet access.  I believe something is overwriting my interfaces settings sometimes on boot.  Any help would be appreciated.  I am running Ubuntu Server 12.04 64bit

/etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback


 auto eth0
 iface eth0 inet static
     address 173.213.192.234
     netmask 255.255.255.248
     network 173.213.192.232
     broadcast 173.213.192.239
     gateway 173.213.192.233
     dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8

 auto eth1
 iface eth1 inet static
     address 10.0.0.106
     netmask 255.255.255.0
     gateway 10.0.0.1
```

Comment: You can't have more than one default gateway. What is that eth1 network?

Comment: eth1 is a local network. eth0 points to the outside network(internet).

Comment: @user1221444 Well, that's not what you tell Ubuntu here by providing two gateways! :) By providing two default routes it will be very random about which one it will actually use to connect to the outside world.

Comment: Does 10.0.0.1 exist? Do you need it to access another network?

Comment: How can I set it up so that my local traffic will go through eth1 and all other traffic will go through eth0?

Comment: @user1221444 Again, remove the gateway from the `eth1` definition. If you need specific networks to be routed over `10.0.0.1` you'll have to set it up manually. You don't have to do anything for 10.0.0.0/24 as that's on the local link of eth1.

Comment: Okay, I removed the gateway for eth1.  I did a `/etc/init.d/networking restart`.  My pings no longer hang when pinging google.com, but I get a `unknown host google.com` message, which leads me to believe I still have a problem with my nameserver not being there. Any clue about that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this `interfaces` file:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 173.213.192.234
    netmask 255.255.255.248
    gateway 173.213.192.233
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
    address 10.0.0.106
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    up route add -net 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.0.0.0 gw 10.0.0.1
    up route add -net 172.16.0.0 netmask 255.240.0.0 gw 10.0.0.1
    up route add -net 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.0.0 gw 10.0.0.1
```

This will redirect all local traffic to 10.0.0.1 and Internet to 173.213.192.233.

Comment: Nevemind, once I rebooted, it worked, I'll mark this as accepted, thank you very much.