# Lubuntu 14.04.2 change network configuration using terminal

Tags: networking, lubuntu, interface

I am sorry to ask about this again, but i cannot figure out, even after reading a lot of articles, how to change my network configuration from command line, without having to restart the machine.

I am using a copy of Lubuntu 14.04.2 LTS, which runs in a VirtualBox VM, and boots up without a GUI interface.

When i want to change my network connection settings using terminal, i usually edit

```
/etc/network/interfaces
```

and then

```
/etc/init.d/networking restart
```

or

```
service networking restart
```

But the above steps that used to work in most of the *ubuntu versions, now seem to do nothing.

I also tried ifdown/ifup and ifconfig, but nothing seems to be able to **restart** the connection and apply the new settings.

The settings are applied **only** if i restart the machine completely.

Is there something i might be missing, or am i stuck with the restart option?
Thanks in advance..

**EDIT : Extra info**
This is how my interfaces file looks like

[Pastebin link : /etc/network/interfaces](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=U7XcaSTD)

Comment: Are you trying: `sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup -v eth0` substituting for eth0 if it is not your relevant interface?

Comment: The truth is that i tried so many commands, that i don't remember all the arguments i have used. I did try `sudo ifdown --exclude=lo -a && sudo ifup --exclude=lo -a` which works in ubuntu server 14.04 but it didn't work.

Comment: Please tell us what you are trying to accomplish with `eth0:1`. It has no reachable gateway. Thanks.

Comment: I am running a server-client application. My backend requires internet but my clients are not allowed to access it. So as a simple solution the clients communicate with the server using the `eth0:1` virtual adapter. I have been using this setup many years successfully with older versions of ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many attempts and system re-installation i managed to do it this way :

```
ip addr flush dev eth0
ifdown --exclude=lo -a && ifup --exclude=lo -a
```

Thanks for all the suggestions.

**EDIT :**

To help novice users like myself i would like to add that if you want to do this remotely using ssh, you would have to execute the above commands in one statement like this :

```
ip addr flush dev eth0 && ifdown --exclude=lo -a && ifup --exclude=lo -a
```

You will be disconnected of course but then you can re-connect on your new ip.

Answer (score 0):

What parameters are you trying to change?

If you are changing your IP to a fixed one maybe the problem is with the router.

Also, when running the restart command, root privileges are needed:

```
sudo service networking restart
```

You can also try to do:

```
sudo service networking stop
sudo service networking start
```

Some links with possible solutions: [link1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/313877/how-do-i-add-an-additional-ip-address-to-etc-network-interfaces), [link2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/45086/how-to-add-an-ip-alias-on-a-bridged-interface?rq=1), [link3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110735/how-do-i-set-a-static-ip-address?rq=1), [link4](https://askubuntu.com/questions/312718/etc-network-interfaces-doesnt-always-take-affect?rq=1).

Comment: I am runnig the commands as root so that is not the problem.

Comment: What about the parameters you are trying to change?

Comment: I updated my question it's all up there :)

Comment: I added some links that might be useful.

Comment: Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site just disappears... :-( Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! ;-) You can always leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your material...